# issue: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to remove "/10" form a rating (ex. 8.9/10)

```
df['IMDb'] = [float(rating[0:3]) for rating in df['IMDb']]
```

I am getting error someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please show how df is defined

Comment: Also if you want to remove the last 3 characters the slice you want is `rating[:-3]`

Comment: does that column contain strings or numbers?  The code assumes strings, the error says at least one is a number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is to remove /10 from IMDb column

```
df[IMDb] = df[IMDb].replace({'/10':''},regex=True)
    print (df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had missing values in the column, used simple imputer to impute most_frequent values and then used the below code and then fixed my problem.

```
df["IMDb"] = [str(score)[0:3] for score in df["IMDb"]]
df = df.astype({"IMDb":'float'})
```